# QGIS: moving one side of polygon parallel

Tags: qgis

I've got a project with different polygon shapes.
Now I´m trying to move only one side of a polygon parallelly and about an exactly defined distance. The result has to be as exactly as possible (a few centimeters).
Is there an add-on which offers me this function?

Answer (score 3):

One plugin I would like to suggest is [Digitizing Tools](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/DigitizingTools/) which can work with both QGIS 2 and 3.

When you install this plugin, a new toolbar is added to QGIS GUI. There are several tools on the toolbar, but the one you need is **Parallel move of polygon side to given distance** (icon with the letter `d`).

[image]

1. Select the polygon you want edit and switch the layer to `Edit mode`.
2. Click on **Parallel move of polygon side to given distance** icon.
3. A small window `Move distance` will appear, but ignore it and select the side of polygon first.
4. Put the distance you want to move the side in the `Move distance` window and click on <kbd>Move side</kbd> button.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @Herman If the answer solved your problem, please accept it so that it can help others.

Comment: when i click move slide button, im getting "Selected segment should be on the selected polygon" error. but its already on the same polygon